# Algolia - WordPress - how can I get the actual query into JS variable to work with it further in the hits template?

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I would like to do some interesting stuff with the hits that are being displayed based on the search query that user is not only typing into search box but actually filtering using the instant search filters. I have filter based on hierarchical events_location taxonomy. Based on what user selected I would get the info in JS variable that I can then further use to do other operations in the hits div, specifically on each hit card.

So my URL when searching updates like this:
/what-to-see/?q=&idx=sdbeta_posts_events&p=0&hFR%5Btaxonomies_hierarchical.events_calendar.lvl0%5D%5B0%5D=JUL%204&hFR%5Btaxonomies_hierarchical.events_category.lvl0%5D%5B0%5D=All&hFR%5Btaxonomies_hierarchical.events_locations.lvl0%5D%5B0%5D=Paddock%20Stage

I could potentially take the URL and extract the data from it, but I am sure there is more elegant way of working with the query.

Answer (score 1):

In InstantSearch.js, the state is managed by another library called the [algoliasearch-helper](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js). Through this library you can read and write the search parameters.

The cleanest to access the helper is to build a custom widget, which is a plain object with lifecycle hooks (initial rendering and the other renderings). You can read more about [custom widgets there](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/guides/custom-widget.html).

Once you've accessed the helper, you can read and write with [the helper API](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be found under search.searchParameters

So:

```
console.log(search.searchParameters);
```

Will give you whole object that you can then work with.

There is however one issue with this and that is that it works only on initial load. I was unable to make this work or get any data after starting to selecting categories. So if anyone knows how to use this so it updates after each selection please comment bellow.